# Ruby Attributing Methods

Tags: ruby, reflection, attributes

I am looking for a way to categorize or attributize methods in classes/modules. I need to tag methods in a class, so when the ruby script launches, I can use reflection to identify modules and classes which contain methods that have a certain tag.

C# has something like this, which is referred to as [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), although the term attributes means something different in ruby. I was curious if this functionality existed.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: to know wheither the class responds to a method, you can use the method `respond_to`. or write an extension to know wheither the class respond to a method group.

Answer (score 1):

You can list methods using .methods

Example

```
class TestClass
  def method1
  end

  def tag_method2
  end

  def method3
  end
end

test = TestClass.new

test.methods
# => [:method1, :tag_method2, :method3, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, ... ]
```

and you can do a select to filter

```
test.methods.select{|m| m.to_s.include? "tag"}
# => [:tag_method2]
```

All class that inherit from Object can execute .methods

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-methods